# Activation/download of Quick Start?

Tags: system-installation

Where/how can I download  ubuntu Quick Start 'cause when I open I open my PC using it, on the screen there's a message telling me to install it...Also,is the Quick Start worth using it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Quick Start"?

Answer (score 2):

If you have downloaded the  [Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) , you should then open it to install Ubuntu. You will find detailed instruction on how to install [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) and "Yes" if you just want to give a try for Ubuntu without leaving Windows on your PC then Wubi is best choice.